# Regex for 8 digits and after that 1 dot and after that only 2 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for accepting eight digits and after that one dot and after that only two digits for amount fields.

Currently I'm using this much of code...

```js
valLowLTL(val) {
    const val1 = val.split('.');
    const amountLowLTL = this.addBillingForm.get('invoicingAmtLowLTL') as FormControl;
    const re = /,/gi;
    val1[0] = val1[0].replace(re, '');
    if (val1[0].length > 8) {
      val1[0] = val1[0].substring(0, 8);
    }
    amountLowLTL.setValue(val1[0]);
    if (val1.length > 1) {
      if (val1[1].length > 2) {
        val1[1] = val1[1].substring(0, 2);
      }
      const lowValLTL = val1[0].concat('.').concat(val1[1]);
      amountLowLTL.setValue(lowValLTL);
    }
}
```

I just need an simple regular expression which helps me out.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: You actually do not validate, you sanitize the input.  Try `amountLowLTL.setValue(val.replace(/^(\d{8})\d*(?:\.(\d{2}.*))?$/, function($0,$1,$2) { return $2 ? $1 + "." + $2 : $1; }))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex:
`^\d{8}[.]\d{2}$`

Comment: Without anchor, this is matching  `abc1234567890123456.12`

Answer (score 1):

```
[\d]{8}\.[\d]{2}
```

or

```
[0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/SBAUc8/1